# dynamic casting at runtime vb.net

Tags: vb.net, casting, dynamictype

I would like to know if this is ok, lets say I have a class somewhere on my project and at some point I will need to cast an object to this class type or another but I can only know this at runtime, so at design time can I do something like this??

```
Dim obj = 'will be assigned something of some type.
Dim typeObj As Type = Type.GetType("xxxx.Foo")
Dim fooVar As Foo = CTypeDynamic(obj, typeObj)
```

will this work as lets says:

```
Dim x As String = "3"
Dim n As Integer = CType(x, Integer)
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean creating an instance of a class at run time?

```
    Dim obj As String = "AssemblyName.YourClassName"
    Dim typeObj As Type = Type.GetType(obj)
    Dim fooVar = Activator.CreateInstance(typeObj)
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if VB has such keyword, in c# I solved it this way:

```
private static T PrivDynamicCast<T>(object obj)
{
   return (T)obj;
}


public static object DynamicCast(object obj, Type targetType)
{
   var dynamicCastMethod = typeof(XType).GetMethod("PrivDynamicCast", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
   var tipizedCasteMethod = dynamicCastMethod.MakeGenericMethod(targetType);
   return tipizedCasteMethod.Invoke(null, new[] { obj });
}
```

You can easily translate it to VB.